# How to adjust the clearance for \fillin command used in tables

Tags: exam

On the following example. I would like to use `\fillin` inside a tabular environment.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\setlength\answerskip{3ex} % No effect

\begin{questions}
\question A regular question \par
The path of the \fillin[righteous] man is beset on all sides
By the inequities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men.

\question Another question \par
\medskip
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{*3{|c}|}
        Foo & Bar & Baz \\ \hline
        A & \fillin[B] & C \\ \hline
        \fillin[D] & E & \fillin[F] \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

But the `\answerskip` command doesn't work on tabulars. How can I adjust the clearance on tables?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\setlength\answerclearance{<lenght>}` (instead of `\setlength\answerskip{3ex}`} ***in the text***. The line will be printed a distance of `\answerclearance` below the baseline.

In the table:

The command `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}` expands the cells vertically by that factor. Use it to make room for the answer in the table.

Use `\setlength\fillinlinelength{<lenght>}` to make the cells wider.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
            
    \setlength\answerclearance{0.5ex} % The line is printed a distance of \answerclearance below the baseline <<<<<<<<<<<<<<    
    
    \begin{questions}
        \question A regular question \par
        The path of the \fillin[righteous] man is beset on all sides
        By the inequities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men.
        
        \question Another question \par
        \medskip
        
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % expand the cells vertically <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \setlength\fillinlinelength{0.25\textwidth} % wider cells  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        
        \begin{center}                          
            \begin{tabular}{*3{|c}|}
                \hline
                Foo & Bar & Baz \\ \hline
                A & \fillin[B] & C \\ \hline
                \fillin[D] & E & \fillin[F] \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```